# Unity multiple Coroutines null reference exception

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have seen the same question with an answer, but unfortunately I haven't fully understood how to address the issue, as I get a null reference exception.

I try to have 2 coroutines run simultaneously. Each is from a different base class. They both are identical, apart from the class's name and activation key (one is Up Arrow and the other Down Arrow).

```
public IEnumerator DetectArrow()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        if (PrintMessage == null)
        {
            PrintMessage += SendMessage;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public void SendMessage()
{
    print("I am B.");
    PrintMessage = null;
}
```

I try to run something such as this for the entire run (from a parent class):

```
void Update () 
{
    if (b.PrintMessage != null)
    {
        b.PrintMessage();
    }
    if (a.PrintMessage != null)
    {
        a.PrintMessage();
    }
 }
```

So I'm not quite sure how to solve this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Confused by this. In your `Update()` function you call `b.PrintMessage()` but you haven't given a definition of what this function is, unless you mean `b.SendMessage()`?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean

Comment: Are you sure `a` and `b` are not `null`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure. If I run it without a coroutine (just as a void function) it all works.

Comment: where and how are you calling your coroutine?

Comment: The code provided shouldn't output a `Null Reference Exception`. As @AdrienDi-Santo suggest, show us how the co-routines are started. Also you could try naming your properties something different than your methods (at least lowercase or use `_`operator). That way its much more clear whats going on, even for yourself I think.

Comment: The problem is when I try to have 2 different classes run a coroutine. I was able to solve it by managing all the coroutines from the same class. The real question is how can I have 2 different classes run coroutines